# Verifying multiple tokens as Ints with Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

/*
My goal is to use the terminal to receive 2 integers and add them together in a Java program. I need to confirm that both terminal entries are ints. If the are, I should proceed to add the ints together. If not, I should print out "Invalid input entered. Terminating..."

I am trying to use an if statement with hasNextInt(), but my program is only verifying the first Scanner input. How do I confirm both Scanner inputs are ints? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Java code:
*/

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("List of operations: add subtract multiply divide alphabetize");
    System.out.println("Enter an operation:");
    String operationInput = input.next().toLowerCase();

    switch (operationInput){

     case "add":// for addition
     System.out.print("Enter two integers:");

      if (input.hasNextInt() == false) { //confirm the numbers are integers, otherwise terminate
        System.out.println("Invalid input entered. Terminating...");
        break;
      }
      else {
         int a1 = input.nextInt();
         int a2 = input.nextInt();
         int at = a1 + a2;
         System.out.println("Answer: " + at);
         input.close();
         break;
      }
```

Comment: Off topic:  I don't know what "Alphabetize" is in a calculator. But, the other operations are all binary. You could improve the code by getting the operation, then getting and verifying the operands. At that point, use the `switch` block to do the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already read the int if it's available and basically, you'll just have to repeat this step. You can use an additional flag to indicate whether the program was able to read the two ints successfully:

```
int a1, a2;
boolean gotTwoInts = false;
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
    a1 = input.nextInt();
}
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
    a2 = input.nextInt();
    gotTwoInts = true;
}

if (!gotTwoInts) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input entered. Terminating... ");
    break;
}
```

**Update**

Complete example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("List of operations: add subtract multiply divide alphabetize");
        System.out.println("Enter an operation:");
        String operationInput = input.next().toLowerCase();

        switch (operationInput){
            case "add": { // curly braces because local variables are block scoped.
                System.out.print("Enter two integers:");

                int a1 = -1, a2 = -1; // local variables need to be initialized
                boolean gotTwoInts = false;
                if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                    a1 = input.nextInt();
                }
                if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                    a2 = input.nextInt();
                    gotTwoInts = true;
                }

                if (!gotTwoInts) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input entered. Terminating... ");
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("Answer: " + (a1 + a2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this approach and I got a run time error: Calculator12.java:42: error: variable a1 is already defined in method main(String[])
               int a1 = input.nextInt();
                   ^
Calculator12.java:43: error: variable a2 is already defined in method main(String[])
               int a2 = input.nextInt();

Comment: Should I change my main(String[]) method to support this code? Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry, this was just a sketch to show how it can be done. I added a runnable example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out based on your earlier example. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I would use method [nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) – rather than method `nextInt` and have the user enter the two integers on a single line, separated by a space.

Also, I think it is a good idea to divide the code into methods and not to write all the code in method `main`.

It appears that you intend to also add *subtract*, *multiply* and *divide* operations, hence part of the below code can be considered as a template to help you complete your program.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_OPERANDS = 2;
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static int[] operands = new int[NUMBER_OF_OPERANDS];

    private static int add() {
        getOperands();
        return operands[0] + operands[1];
    }

    private static void getOperands() {
        System.out.print("Enter two integers separated by space: ");
        String value = input.nextLine();
        String[] parts = value.split("\\s+");
        if (parts.length < NUMBER_OF_OPERANDS) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Less than two integers entered.");
        }
        operands[0] = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        operands[1] = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("List of operations: add subtract multiply divide alphabetize");
        System.out.print("Enter an operation: ");
        String operationInput = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        int result = 0;
        switch (operationInput) {
            case "add":// for addition
                result = add();
                break;
            case "subtract":
                break;
            case "multiply":
                break;
            case "divide":
                break;
            case "alphabetize":
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid operation: " + operationInput);
                System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Note that `RuntimeException` is an unchecked [exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) and that [static] method `parseInt` – of class `java.lang.Integer` – may throw `NumberFormatException` which is also an unchecked exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could change the structure. Instead of the `if ( ! input.hasNextInt())` and `else` block, you could use a `try` block and `catch` the exceptions `input.nextint()` will throw if there are not two integers. [Scanner API # nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt())

```
System.out.print("Enter two integers:");
try {
  int a1 = input.nextInt();
  int a2 = input.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Answer: " + (a1 + a2));
}
catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
   System.out.println("Invalid input entered. Terminating...");
   System.exit (100); }
catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
   System.out.println("Missing input. Expected two integers."
                        + " Terminating...");
   System.exit (100); }
finally { 
   input.close();
}
```

Comment: Note: I do not have a Java IDE on this computer. I did not attempt to verify the code is correct.

Comment: Java 7 and later allows more than one exception to be specified with one `catch`:   `catch ( InputMismatchException | NoSuchElementException ex) { System.out.printlin ("Two integers were expected, but not found. Terminating ..."); System.exit (100); }`